# draw a bezier curve but the canvas stays blank

Tags: javascript, canvas, bezier

Here's my code. I'm new to JavaScript so I'm having trouble finding what's wrong with my code. I tried adding alerts to various parts of the function to check which parts work without much success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function BEZIER() {
    var X = ["0,0,0,0,0"];
    var Y = ["0,0,0,0,0"];
    X[0] = document.getElementById("X0");
    Y[0] = document.getElementById("Y0");
    X[0] = document.getElementById("X1");
    Y[0] = document.getElementById("Y1");
    X[0] = document.getElementById("X2");
    Y[0] = document.getElementById("Y2");
    X[0] = document.getElementById("X3");
    Y[0] = document.getElementById("Y3");
    X[0] = document.getElementById("X4");
    Y[0] = document.getElementById("Y4");
    var A;
    var B;
    var T = 0;
    while (T <= 1) {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 5) {
            A[i] = X[i];
            B[i] = Y[i];
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        var j = 5;
        while (j > 1) {
            i = 0;
            while (i < j) {
                A[i] = A[i] * (1 - T) + A[i + 1] * T;
                B[i] = B[i] * (1 - T) + B[i + 1] * T;
                i++;
            }
            j--;
        }
        T = T + 0.1;
        var S = document.getElementById("a");
        var ctx = S.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(A[0], B[0], 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Introduceti coordonatele cu valori intre 0 si 800</p> <br>
    <form>punctul 0: X=<input type="number" id="X0" name="X0" >, Y=<input type="number" id="Y0" name="Y0" ><br></form>  
    <form>punctul 1: X=<input type="number" id="X1" name="X1" >, Y=<input type="number" id="Y1" name="Y1" ><br></form>
    <form>punctul 2: X=<input type="number" id="X2" name="X2" >, Y=<input type="number" id="Y2" name="Y2" ><br></form>
    <form>punctul 3: X=<input type="number" id="X3" name="X3" >, Y=<input type="number" id="Y3" name="Y3" ><br></form>
    <form>punctul 4: X=<input type="number" id="X4" name="X4" >, Y=<input type="number" id="Y4" name="Y4" ><br></form>   
    <button onclick="BEZIER()">!DESENATI!</button><br><br>
     <canvas id="a" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>

</body>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using console.log() and Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools rather than just putting alerts in javascript to debug your code

Comment: I recommend going through the MDN tutorials, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript , before taking on drawing curves on a canvas as an early js project.

Comment: Why not use the built-in bezierCurveTo() method? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/

Comment: I'm trying to do it from scratch. I know the maths but my Js skills are at a beginner level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your code, that's why it doesn't do anything.

First, in your loop, you are using variables A and B, but without initializing them. Try `var A = []; var B = [];`

Also, if you want to get the value of your `input` tags, you have to do

```
document.getElementById("X0").value
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("X0")
```

But what's really weird is that you're always assigning a new value to the same elements of X and Y :

```
X[0] = ...something...
X[0] = ...something else...
```

Also, when you create your X and Y arrays, you are actually just creating arrays with a single string as an element... try this instead :

```
var X = [0,0,0,0,0];
var Y = [0,0,0,0,0]; // without the "
```

But as someone already said, I suggest you read more about the syntax of Javascript before attempting to code something that is much too hard for you. Start with the basics, as everybody does when they start programming in a new language...